# Passing variables to a Django generic view template using reverse()

Tags: django, django-templates, reverse

I have a urlpatterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    (r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict, 'poll_detail'),
...
```

My html page template contains this:

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
```

My view code contains:

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_detail',args=(p.id,)))
```

My question is, where in the reverse() call do I place my 'error_message' variable value?

Apologies if this is a stupid question but I have attempted to search the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) converts a view name to a URL. It does not call the view. Also, it can only set arguments in the URL; it cannot set template tags.

What you can do is make `error_message` an argument to the `poll_detail` view. This way, you can pass its value to the view using `reverse()`.